# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create table for some courses, wհօse last column is another table and presents the lecturers names.

```
class Teachers(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'teacher'
    full_name = Column(String, unique=False, primary_key=True)
    company = Column(String, unique = False)
    

class Course(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'course'
    course_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    course_id = Column(String,primary_key=True)
    level = Column(String,unique=False)
    teachers = Teachers
```

But I found following issue when the name of one lecturer is repeated in different courses:

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: teacher.full_name

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are trying to add a second `Teachers` to the DB with the same `full_name`, but it is the primary key. Perhaps you meant to fetch the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

Your `teachers` column is not a column. Instead you are adding a whole table as an attribute.

What you should do, is defining a column in `Course` that contains the primary key of the `Teacher` (assuming there is only one teacher per course) and mark it as a `ForeignKey`. You can than also add a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html) for easier work.

```py
from pathlib import Path

import sqlalchemy.orm
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship

Base = declarative_base()


class Teacher(Base):
    __tablename__ = "teachers"

    full_name = Column(String, unique=False, primary_key=True)
    company = Column(String, unique=False)


class Course(Base):
    __tablename__ = "courses"

    course_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    course_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    level = Column(String, unique=False)
    teacher_name = Column(ForeignKey("teachers.full_name"))

    teacher = relationship("Teacher")


def main():
    if Path("test_database.db").exists():
        Path("test_database.db").unlink()

    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test_database.db")

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    session = sqlalchemy.orm.Session(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

    teacher_1 = Teacher(full_name="Bob")

    course_1 = Course(course_id=1, course_name="Course 1", level="beginner", teacher=teacher_1)
    course_2 = Course(course_id=2, course_name="Course 2", level="advanced", teacher=teacher_1)

    session.add_all([course_1, course_2])
    session.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```